# Webstorm 10.0.4: makes wrong indentation for Jade. How to fix it?

Tags: pug, webstorm

Webstorm 10.0.4, lates version, reformat on paste disabled, Java is up to date.

Problem:
When I use auto indentation WebStorm makes it following:

```
mixin ol(list)
    ol
        - each item in list
        li= item
```

**but it have to be:**

```
mixin ol(list)
    ol
        - each item in list
            li= item
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. Logged as [WEB-18551](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18551), please follow it for updates